# How to shift a power series to be centered at a?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

Let's say that I want to approximate $\sin{(4)}$ Using a the first three non-zero terms of a power series. If I'm centered at $x=0$, I get a bad approximation, as you can see in the image.

[image]

How do I get a better approximation, not by adding more terms to the power series, but by finding a different power series centered at $x=4$? If I just use the Taylor Series, the first term would be $\sin{(4)}$, but that defeats the purpose - I can't use $\sin{(4)}$ if I'm trying to approximate $\sin{(4)}$. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you probably don't mean "centered at $x=4$"...you want it to be centered at a value near $4$, a value for which you can compute the power series.  $x=\pi$ isn't a bad start.  Or $x=\frac {5\pi}4$.

Comment: You can shift the sine function by using $\sin(a+h) = \sin(a)\cos(h)+\cos(a)\sin(h)$

Comment: So it's not possible to center it exactly at $x=4$ unless I already know the value of $\sin{(4)}$? So I pick a value close to $4$ that is a know sin value?

Comment: @Gribouillis How does that help? Where would I go from there?

Comment: @user3925803 you can write $\sin(4) = -\sin(4 - \pi)$, which gives you small value of argument (assuming $\pi$ is known). This will the same result as expanding $\sin$ at $x = \pi$. Of course, in both cases it's assumed that $\pi$ is known with good precision - if not, you need either more terms or different approach.

Comment: The first term of the Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at $x=a$ is $f(a)$. In deriving the standard Taylor series for $\sin x$, we use that $\sin 0 = 0$ and that $\cos 0 = 1$. The Taylor series is good for approximating a function in the vicinity of the center, In addition to needing to know the value, it also won't look very nice (or be easy to calculate) if centered at $x=4$. Looking at your graph to see how good 5 terms (two are zero so they are normally left out) approximate $\sin$, I would suggest going for a series centered at $x=\pi$.

Comment: Closely related and possibly useful: [What does expanding $e^{2x}$ in powers of $\left(x-1\right)$ means?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689743/25554)

Comment: @Gribouillis formula is not wrong, but perhaps a bit to general. I think you can derive all the shifts you need from (multiple applications of) the simpler $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)=\sin(x+\pi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the suggestions in the comments, I have expanded the series around $\pi$. Including terms up through $x^3$ seems to approximate $\sin 4$ pretty well already.

The even-numbered terms are multiples of $\sin \pi = 0$, so I have omitted them from this display.

[image: graph of first three nonzero terms of Taylor series for sin(x) around x=\pi]
[image: graph of sin(x), sum of terms up to x^3, sum of terms up to x^5]

[Interactive hilarity](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e4trishcoo)